# How to create a class and add to a list in a for loop receiving the input from console

Tags: java, class, object, constructor

I have a class `ProductMaster` that i want to create and add to a list in a for loop receiving the input from console.

The class is the following:

```
public class ProductMaster {

    String productName;
    double productPrice; // ... so on

    ProductMaster() {  }

    ProductMaster(String prodN, double prodP, int discQ, double discP) {
        productName=prodN;
        // ...
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // ... hardcoded values for example
        // ... trying to achieve this dynamically by using a for loop, 
        // ProductMaster milk = new ProductMaster("Milk",3.97,2,5.00)
        // list.add(milk);
        // trying to create the above two lines by using for loops

        for (int i=0; i<n; i++) { 
            System.out.println("Enter the item name:");
            String n1 = br.readLine();
            System.out.println("Enter the item price:");
            Double n2 = Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());

            // taking input from console

            ProductMaster n12 = new ProductMaster(n12, n2, n3, n4);
            list.add(new ProductMaster(n12, n2, n3, n4));
        }

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
  ArrayList<ProductMaster> list=new ArrayList<ProductMaster>();
    System.out.println(choice);
try{
        if(choice.toLowerCase().equals("yes"))
        {
        System.out.println("You entered yes, Now please enter number of new items");
        n=Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());

        System.out.println("You have chosed to enter items"+n);

        for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
            {
               System.out.println("Enter the item name:");
               String n1=br.readLine();
              System.out.println("Entered:"+n1);
               System.out.println("Enter the item price:");
                Double n2=Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
                System.out.println("Entered:"+n2);
               System.out.println("Enter the item sale quantity");
               n3 =Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
               System.out.println("Entered:"+n3);
               System.out.println("Enter the item sale price");
               Double n4=Double.parseDouble(br.readLine());
               System.out.println("Entered:"+n4);

             ProductMaster newC= new ProductMaster(n1,n2,n3,n4);
             list.add(newC);
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a `Scanner` to read input(separated by spaces and different items on different lines) from the console.  Plug this in your code(instead of hardcoding values)

```
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    String[] strArray;
    List<ProductMaster> list = new ArrayList<>();

    while(sc.hasNextLine()){
        strArray = sc.nextLine().split("\\s+"); //considering space separated values
        ProductMaster productMaster= new ProductMaster(
                strArray[0], Double.parseDouble(strArray[1]),Integer.parseInt(strArray[2]),Double.parseDouble(strArray[2]));
        list.add(productMaster);
    }
    sc.close();
 //list size
 System.out.println(list.size());
```

Comment: ProductMaster milk= new ProductMaster("Milk",3.97,2,5.00);
            ProductMaster bread= new ProductMaster("Bread",2.17,3,6.00);
            ProductMaster banana= new ProductMaster("Banana",0.99,0,0.0);

Comment: @RonHilkin whats the question here?

Comment: 1..ProductMaster milk= new ProductMaster("Milk",3.97,2,5.00);
2..ProductMaster bread= new ProductMaster("Bread",2.17,3,6.00);
3..ProductMaster banana= new ProductMaster("Banana",0.99,0,0.0);

4..list.add(milk);
       
5..list.add(bread);
            
6..list.add(banana);

@HumbleFoolish in the same scenario, the whole 1-6 lines,can they be dynamically generated using for loop 
for{ 
 //using bufferedreader
                String n1=..
                Double n2=..
            ProductMaster n1= new ProductMaster(n1,n2,n3,n4);
            list.add(new ProductMaster(n1,n2,n3,n4));

Comment: @RonHilkin I have edited the code to make it little more clear and added the initialization of list outside for loop. So, lines 1-6 in your comment are automated by the for loop. And, after the for loop ends, your list should have 3 products (If you input 3 lines from your console)